If $xy + yz + zx = 0$, then find the value of $\frac{1}{x^2-yz} + \frac{1}{y^2 - zx} + \frac{1}{z^2 - xy}$ .

If $xy + yz + zx = 0$, then find the value of $\frac{1}{x^2-yz} + \frac{1}{y^2 - zx} + \frac{1}{z^2 - xy}$ .

The problem seems simple the numerator comes out to be $xy + yz + zx = 0$ but how can the answer be 0 without being sure that the denominator $xyz(x + y + z)$ would be something non zero ?
There would be two cases one in which $x = y = z = 0$ which is not to consider as the answer won't be finite but the other case seems complicated .

Are there no restrictions on $x,y,z$? I'd anticipate that at least you have the constraint that $x,y,z$ are nonzero. As far as I can tell, if at least one is nonzero, then the other two are either both nonzero or both zero, with both cases being possible. In the former case, then $x+y+z \neq 0$ and everything is well defined, in the latter case, the expression you want is undefined.

I would start with noticing that
\begin{align*}
x^{2} - yz = x^{2} + xy + xz = x(x + y + z)
\end{align*}
Similarly, one may conclude that
\begin{align*}
y^{2} - zx = y(x + y + z)
\end{align*}
as well as
\begin{align*}
z^{2} - xy = z(x + y + z)
\end{align*}
Consequently, it results that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{x^{2} - yz} + \frac{1}{y^{2} - zx} + \frac{1}{z^{2} - xy} & = \frac{yz + zx + xy}{xyz(x + y + z)} = 0
\end{align*}
as long as the involved denominators are different from zero.
Hopefully this helps!
